# Foundations types unknown after installing RestKit 0.20.0 via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, restkit, cocoapods

I've been looking for an answer but could not find somebody with a similar problem.

I have installed RestKit 0.20.0 in my project, using the recommended method (cocoapods), with the following Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '5.1' 
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0'
```

My problem is now that all Foundation (and UIKit) types are not found. Here are a few examples:

```
.../Block.h:11:20: Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView', superclass of 'Block'
.../Block.h:14:38: Unknown type name 'UIImageView'
.../Block.h:28:23: Unknown type name 'NSInteger'
```

I've tried all the tips on this page: http://docs.cocoapods.org/guides/integrating_a_project.html

Also, it's worth mentioning that I could successfully install Reskit via Cocoapods in an empty new project (no compile errors). I compared the Build settings of the two projects, they are the same.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: seems like some dynamic library dependency like QuartzCore or UIKit is missing in your "non-empty old" project

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems to, but Foundation, UIKit and QuartzCore are actually in the Build Phases, and imported in the prefix.pch file (and importing in my classes does not solve the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution, but I still don't understand the root of the problem.

The errors were actually appearing in 1 class only (Block). The name "Block" seemed to be the cause as renaming the class to something else solved the problem (deleting the class and re-creating it was not enough, a rename was necessary).

What I don't understand is that the usual error for this case is "duplicate symbol".